# SQL remove duplicates with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have tried multiple things to get rid of all the duplicates in my query result, none of them worked. I tried `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`.

`DISTINCT` won't do anything at all and with `GROUP BY` I keep getting errors.

My Query:

```
SELECT        
   categorie.categorie_id AS categorie, 
   categorie.categorie_nummer, 
   categorie.naam, 
   product.product_id, product.product_naam, 
   foto.foto_id, foto.foto1, 
   item.prijs, item.item_id
FROM            
   ((((((categorie 
INNER JOIN 
   behoort_tot ON categorie.categorie_id = behoort_tot.categorie_id) 
INNER JOIN
   product ON behoort_tot.product_id = product.product_id) 
INNER JOIN
   heeft ON product.product_id = heeft.product_id) 
INNER JOIN
   foto ON heeft.foto_id = foto.foto_id) 
INNER JOIN
   is_een_1 ON product.product_id = is_een_1.product_id) 
INNER JOIN
   item ON is_een_1.item_id = item.item_id)
WHERE        
   (categorie.categorie_id = ?)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `DISTINCT` alone should work.

Comment: Can you add the results you're getting with and without the `DISTINCT` clause?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i wanted to upload an image of my results but it wont let me under 10 rep. But the output is exactly the same with or without DISTINCT

Comment: Use pastebin to show your results. Better yet, use sqlfiddle to show the structure of your tables and some demo data.

Comment: It would be alot of work to add all my tables

Comment: Are you saying that you have multiple rows in the resultset that are identical when you are using DISTINCT?

Comment: If `DISTINCT` doesn't do anything - then you don't have duplicates.... it might *look* like duplicates, but as long as at least one column has a different value from another row, it's not

Comment: Thanks alot, it was kinda late when i started to work on this, i cant use all fields cause some of them have different values THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

```
    WITH TEMP AS
       (

    SELECT categorie.categorie_id AS categorie, categorie.categorie_nummer, categorie.naam, 
    product.product_id, product.product_naam, foto.foto_id, foto.foto1, item.prijs, item.item_id,
    ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER (PARTITION BY categorie.categorie_id ORDER BY categorie.categorie_id) As ROW_NO


FROM            ((((((categorie INNER JOIN
                         behoort_tot ON categorie.categorie_id = behoort_tot.categorie_id) 
INNER JOIN
                         product ON behoort_tot.product_id = product.product_id) INNER JOIN
                         heeft ON product.product_id = heeft.product_id) INNER JOIN
                         foto ON heeft.foto_id = foto.foto_id) INNER JOIN
                         is_een_1 ON product.product_id = is_een_1.product_id) INNER JOIN
                         item ON is_een_1.item_id = item.item_id)

)
SELECT * FROM TEMP WHERE ROW_NO = 1;
```

I do see that you are trying to sort out using the categories.Try this.I`m sorting it using the row_number function and assuming that you are using sql server

Comment: I`m not sure on that.Anyway Give a try